# Most Popular Mysql Row over last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

In one table I have

ID, PAGE_ID, DATE

Each time a page is loaded, the DATE, PAGE_ID [from the page table below] are loaded into the table above.

I am trying to calculate and sort pages by popularity. The page table contains:

ID [PAGE_ID], DESCRIPTION, DATE

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select L.PAGE_ID, P.DESCRIPTION, count(L.ID) from LOADED_PAGE L 
inner join PAGE P on P.ID = L.PAGE_ID
where L.DATE > :sevenDaysAgo 
group by L.PAGE_ID, P.DESCRIPTION
order by count(L.ID) desc
```

will give you the list of loaded pages, from the most popular to the least one.

Comment: You cannot order by `count()`, instead you should alias the column name in the first line and use the alias in order by. Still +1 for PDO start date input.

Comment: Yes you can, at least in postgreSQL and oracle. I would be surprised if it didn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
id_page,
count(*) as popularity
from table
where date >= curdate() - interval 7 day
group by id_page
order by popularity desc
```

Comment: Nick, it looks like this will sort table1 but not table2 [page table].?

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood your question. Then you have to use join as JB Nizet suggests :)